# WCF POST Service 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf

Here is the WCF POST Service with ajaxcallback. Its working fine on my side but not working on Client Side. It is giving error - POST http://localhost/WCFService/EService.svc/GetTIDFromRID 500 (internal server error).

Method:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
                  )]
    string GetTIDFromRID(string RID);
```

Service Web.Config:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="c:\logs\northwindservices.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
              logEntireMessage="false"
              logMalformedMessages="true"
              logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
              logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
              maxMessagesToLog="500"
              maxSizeOfMessageToLog="5000"/>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>


  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <authentication mode="None"></authentication>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ConStr" value="Data Source=C002;Initial Catalog=TEST;User ID=sa;Password=sa"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="EcubeBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <!--<webHttp/>-->
                    <enableWebScript/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="WCFService.EService" behaviorConfiguration="EBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/WCFService/EService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IEService"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WCFService/EService.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

        <standardEndpoints>
            <webScriptEndpoint>
                <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
            </webScriptEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
```

Service Consumption:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/WCFService/EService.svc/GetTIDFromRID',
        data: JSON.stringify({ "RID": "r1234" }),
        dataType:  'json',
        type:   'POST',
        contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
         },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Response: Failed');
        }
    });
```

Please give some suggestion. Both Application and Service are hosted on different server. Permission is also given. Global.asax is also added which contains Header related code Access origin...

Answer (score 5):

A `500 internal server error` indicates that the error originates with the web service host.

In order to help track down the issue, you may want to consider configuring server-side WCF tracing, which will record operation calls, code exceptions, warnings and other significant processing events.  Once WCF tracing is configured and enable, send the message that generates the http status 500 error and review the trace log for any underlying errors.

Use the `WCF Service Configuration Editor` (Visual Studio -> Tools menu) to set the `system.diagnostics` trace values and the corresponding `system.serviceModel` section of the configuration file (example entries below):

system.diagnostics

```
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="wcf_trace_log.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

system.serviceModel

```
  <system.serviceModel>
   <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
      <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true"/>
    </diagnostics>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx